# Getting the total sales of each seller

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a mongo db with documents representing a product item like the following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("548c2a140c2c375d261a7238"),
"statuses" : [
    {
        "item_status_id" : ObjectId("548c2a140c2c375d261a7239"),
        "sold" : 82,
        "price" : 1899
    },
    {
        "item_status_id" : ObjectId("548f282c0c2c371a72a47ae8"),
        "sold" : 84,
        "price" : 1899
    },
    {
        "item_status_id" : ObjectId("548f5ed70c2c37204d35cfa4"),
        "sold" : 85,
        "price" : 1899
    },
    {
        "item_status_id" : ObjectId("54904a090c2c3719de96c6cf"),
        "sold" : 86,
        "price" : 1899
    }
],
"item_id" : "MLM470322597",
"title" : "Sony Xperia Miro St23 4gb 5mpx Android 4.0 Wifi 3g",
"seller_id" : 20906313,
}
```

I'd like to rank the top sellers(using seller_id) by total sold items. The value "sold" has to be pulled from the last position(86 in the case above) of the "statuses" array.

I've been looking at the mongodb documentation and I think this could be done with the $group clause.

This is what I've got so far:

```
db.items.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : $seller_id,
           totalSold: { $sum: ?? },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I get the query to sum the last "sold" item of the "statuses" array in order to aggregate them. I've been looking at the "$slice" operator but I didn't get good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your aggregate pipeline as below:

- `Unwind` the statuses array to separate the sub documents in the
  statuses array.
- `Group` together again so that we may get the last status in the array,
  using the [$last](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator.
- Then again `group` the records based on the `seller_id` so that we can
  get the `$sum` of the total sold items.
- `Sort` by `total_sold` in descending order.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$statuses"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "sold":{$last:"$statuses.sold"},
         "seller_id":{$last:"$seller_id"}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$seller_id",
         "total_sold":{$sum:"$sold"}}},
{$sort:{"total_sold":-1}}
])
```